# Can someone explain why do I get this output in Python?

Tags: python, arguments, function-call

[image]So, I'm trying to call the function grocery_shopping- which accepts as arguments-greeting, an iterable (emp_name) and a dictionary (items).
I'm passing arguments by keywords. 
However the output seems slightly weird since the argument passed as emp_name is being read as items! 
Can anyone help me in deciphering this (seemingly odd) behavior?

Comment: please provide text code and output instead of a screenshot of what it does

Comment: Why do you have `*` and `**` on the declarations of the `emp_name` and `items` parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function with a parameter like `*args` in python, it collects all the unnamed, non key-worded variables into a list named `args`.  When you define a function with a parameter like `**kwargs` in python, it collects all of your key-worded variables into a dictionary named `kwargs`, where the key is the variable name and the value is the value.  So what you've done is put `17.08.2019` into the `greeting` parameter, put nothing into `emp_names`, and put the key-worded arguments into `items`.  Your first for loop will do nothing because `emp_names` is empty.  In your second for loop, you print the dictionary `items` twice.

Google `*args` and `**kwargs` in python if you're still confused.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `emp_name` and `items` as named args, therefore they *both* get included in `**items`.  `*emp_name` is empty.

You should read up on `*args` and `**kwargs`.